# Links in IHTMLDocument2

Tags: delphi, ihtmldocument2

I use `IHTMLDocument2` to retrieve strings with `innertext` in `TD` Tag and I have links to recover but I do not find how using an `innerhtml` I see my link but I do not know how to retrieve it.

**My HTML**

```
<td class="hidden-sm hidden-xs">
    <a href="** My URL **">
        <i class="fa fa-cube" aria-hidden="true"></i>**My Title**
    </a>
</td>
```

in innerhtml I have as a result `<a href="** My URL **"> <i class = "fa fa-cube" aria-hidden = "true"> </ i> ** My Title ** </a>`
I want to recover the contents of the 'href'

**My code**

```
for i := 0 to doc.body.all.length  do
  begin
       el := doc.body.all.item(i);
       if (el.tagName = 'TD') then
       Begin
            Title := el.innerText;
            URL := el.??;
```

Comment: It's a little unclear. What is `innethtml`? Is that just a typo? How about you include some example HTML and indicate which part of that HTML you wish to obtain.

Comment: Try: `URL := el.FirstChild.GetAttribute('href');`

Comment: its walking except there is a `about:` before each URL just put a `Replace` and I get what I want Thank you for your answer

Comment: what karliwson said or See IHTMLElementCollection

Comment: Why not use the [`doc.anchors`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752583.aspx) collection instead of `doc.all`? Walk the `anchors` collection, checking each [`IHTMLAnchorElement`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa741833.aspx) if its [`parentElement`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh870271.aspx) is a `td` element, and if so then read the [`IHTMLAnchorElement.href`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh869662.aspx) property

Comment: Hi Remy Lebeau, my code is more complicated than the piece of code that I post I have 10 `TD` that I recover their `innertext` there is only one that I recover a link

Comment: Your TD element is not going to also have an href attribute. You will need to walk more of the nodes inside of the TD element.